# Skyrim Mod Organizer, hearthfires.esm is grey instead of white?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim, mods, skyrim-hearthfire

I haven't been using Mod Organizer for very long. I started modding with a lot of graphics mods. Now I have the three DLC's, but when I click on the Plugins tab, on the right my `Dragonborn.esm` and `Dawnguard.esm` plugins have white text but `Hearthfires.esm` has grey text. I'm worried that Mod Organizer isn't viewing `Hearthfires.esm` as a master file, which it supposedly should be, and that this will create some problems with my mods, especially ELFX.

Tl;dr-In the Plugins Tab on Mod Organizer should `Hearthfires.esm` have grey text or white text?